# Elementary Particles of Physics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics

Most elementary particles are classified under the 'Lepton' category. This excludes the gauge bosons, of course. So, let me use the electron as an example. An elementary particle is one which cannot be broken down into further particles. Therefore, the interpretation I have of this is that the electron, and all other elementary particles, are just points in space. So that brings me to my first question: If the electron has a certain mass but is just a point in space, and thus does not have a volume, wouldn't its density diverge to infinity? Of course, I'm ignoring the part where it could diverge to negative infinity since that would be less physical than it diverging to positive infinity.

The second thing that I've been reading about is the whole business with the electron being 'spherical' in nature. From what I've read, this 'spherical' nature of the electron is linked to the distribution of charge on the electron and how it is distributed symmetrically. Again, I don't quite understand what this means. If the electron truly is a point, then how is it that there is any 'distribution' of charge in the first place?

Comment: @AbhijeetVats consider the electron as a wave-like object instead. For some interactions it is useful to view the electron as a point particle, but not for the purposes of describing the properties of the electron itself.

Comment: Sure I understand all of this talk about the charge distribution etc. I understand that there is a wave interpretation of the electron, and in fact, all matter that can be reconciled easily with the matter interpretation. What I don't get is the following; if we talk about charge distributions, there should be an object that the charge is distributed on. Otherwise it's a point charge. Are you implying that, in fact, the charge is distributed on the electron throughout the wave and it's distributed in a largely uniform manner?

Comment: In that case, then I have the following question. How does it make sense to think of charge as being distributed on a wave? Why does that make sense? If we're still thinking of the electron as a particle, then a symmetric distribution means that the density of charge diverges to infinity, as in the case of the mass density. I don't quite understand where this is going physically.

Comment: Physically, you are still thinking classically. There is nothing in the world around us like an elementary particle, so we have nothing to compare it to. But at the same time, this "thing" whatever an electron is, has **properties** that do correspond with our measurements and that is the problem we have. But if we stop trying to think classically, and think  in math terms, then we can describe things, and more importantly, predict things.  Physics is really not that concerned with what an electron **is** so much as what it's measureable  properties are.

Comment: Oh so in other words, it doesn't matter whether there's a physical interpretation of these properties or not, as long as the mathematics can produce a measurable property? I'm getting the feeling that in the more advanced stages of physics, it's less about visualizing what you're trying to understand and more about trying to make the mathematics related to it work. At the very least, that's the feeling I get when I read about things such as negative pressures or imaginary masses

Comment: Exactly.  you know the standard model,it's not a list of things or objects, it's a list of properties and interaction. The more you ask what a particle is, the more you get into philosophy, not physics. Anytime you try and think of an electron as a very small cricket ball, you will go wrong....nobody can tell you what elementary particles are, they can only tell you what laws they follow. Eventually, you end up looking at the equations as more important than anything else, because we can work with them, and forget the quantum "thing"

Comment: There are two books I would recommend 1. Deep down things by Bruce Schumm and The infinity puzzle by Frank Close. They might/might not be hard going, not for the math,  they don't have any, but the abstract ideas and the way physicists think. Best of luck in the future

Answer (score 2):

> Most elementary particles are classified under the 'Lepton' category.

Wrong, in the [standard model of particle physics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) most are fermions, but not leptons, as quarks come in three colors

[image: elempart]

They are all point particles in a field theoretical quantum mechanical model.

Density etc have nothing to do with  [quantum mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_mechanics), it is a classical concept, and the elementary particles are quantum mechanical entities . In the standard model at each point in space there exists a field representing all the particles in the table and the number operators of each field generate the number of electrons, or photons or etc at (x,y,z,t) points.

Measured particles , depending on the boundary conditions of the problem, can be represented by wave packets. Still density or charge distribution  cannot be defined in the classical sense. Depending on the boundary conditions it might appear as a probability wave or as a particle.

Comment: 'Still density or charge distribution cannot be defined in the classical sense' So is there a way to define such concepts within quantum mechanics?

Even though the discussion in the comments above sort of quelled some of my doubts, there are still things that I'm thinking about. From what I've learnt in QM so far, the electron can be defined as a probability wave or as a particle, depending on the experiment or the situation.In that case, if you define it as a particle, is it not possible to define, quantum mechanically, a density or a charge distribution? Also, thanks for the answer.

Comment: In the formalism of quantum field theory it will appear as a wavepacket. In the simpler solution sof Shrodingers equation, an electron for example is in an orbital, a probability locus, and a charge distribution can be defined using this probability locus.

Comment: Oh okay okay, that works. Would that also be how a mass density might be defined?

Comment: Yes, as a probability locus in a specific boundary value problem, as an atom for example